VSCode/Pylance - fail to import specific class
I'm trying out VSCode for Django development instead of PyCharm. I'm quite happy with the new configuration, but there's an issue which is driving me mad: VSCode fails to suggest only specific classes from django lib.
So far, I'm able to get import suggestions like this:
and selecting the class will import it correctly.
But, if I try with ListView or LoginRequiredMixin, this happens:


where django_tables2.views and hijack.views are third party libraries.
If I search for additional import matches, the two classes are not found


This is my VSCode workspace configuration:
{
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "."
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.analysis.autoFormatStrings": true,
    "python.analysis.autoSearchPaths": false,
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.callArgumentNames": "off",
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.functionReturnTypes": true,
    "python.analysis.userFileIndexingLimit": -1,
    "python.analysis.indexing": true,
    "python.analysis.stubPath": "",
    "python.analysis.inlayHints.variableTypes": true,
    "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "off",
    "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
    "python.analysis.packageIndexDepths": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "depth": 10,
            "includeAllSymbols": true
        },
    ],
    "python.experiments.enabled": false,
}

Is this a bug or something?
I found many issues on the Pylance repository, but in my case the files are correctly indexed (I can find UpdateView and other django classes).
I also tried to uninstall the 3rd party libraries except for Django, but the LoginRequiredMixin and CreateView are not found anyway.
I have Microsoft official extensions only, everything else is disabled.

At the end, the problem was related to the "includeAllSymbols": true, which blindly import everything from everywhere.
Changing it to false solved the issue.
Relevant GitHub issue here
